# Amazon developer keeps telling me an error in functional test about not validating the requests

Tags: node.js, http, alexa-skills-kit

Im currently trying to deploy an alexa skill but when i try to submit it for review it keeps telling me that im not validating the signatures, i dont know how exactly to implement this on the code.

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();
var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
var languageStrings = require('./languageStrings.js');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a resources object.
    alexa.resources = languageStrings;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
const verifier = require('alexa-verifier')


verifier(cert_url, signature, requestRawBody, function callbackFn(er) {
  // if er, something went wrong
})

var handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit('GetFact');
    },
    'GetNewFactIntent': function () {
        this.emit('GetFact');
    },
    'GetFact': function () {
        // Get a random fact from the fact list
        // Use this.t() to get corresponding language data
        var factArr = this.t('FACTS');
        var factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * factArr.length);
        var randomFact = factArr[factIndex];

        // Create speech output
        var speechOutput = this.t("GET_FACT_MESSAGE") + randomFact;
        this.emit(':tellWithCard', speechOutput, this.t("SKILL_NAME"), randomFact)
    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        var speechOutput = this.t("HELP_MESSAGE");
        var reprompt = this.t("HELP_MESSAGE");
        this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, reprompt);
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', this.t("STOP_MESSAGE"));
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', this.t("STOP_MESSAGE"));
    }
};`
```

if someone can help me with some type of tutorial or something, im so lost, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are hosting the skills on a custom web service. Any skill which has a custom service as a backend needs to verify that the request it gets is sent by the Alexa Service.

If you are using SDKs provided by the Alexa team, here is a [good documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#verify-request-sent-by-alexa) on how to verify this.

If you want to skip this entirely, it would be better to use AWS Lambda as a backend or choose Alexa Hosted as an option while building the skill.